# How to check the largest contiguous free blocks in matlab on linux?

Tags: linux, matlab, memory-management

In windows, I can check the largest contiguous free blocks via 'feature memstats'. But this does not work on linux. I am currently working on a project which needs to load a very large matrix(59107200*17). And I ran into 'out of memory' error. Is there any way to check this and other memory infomation in matlab on linux?

Comment: use `single` for such large arrays. If you are not so particular about precision.

Comment: Yeah, I already used single, but the problem still remains.

Comment: how much is your RAM?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `memory` function? I think it should be available on Linux as well.

**Added**

By the way, 59107200*17 array of doubles require about 8 Gb of memory (each double number occupies 8 bytes). Do you have it?

Comment: Yeah, but memory does not work on linux. My computer's RAM is exactly 8GB. I know it is probably not enough but I just want to check the largest contiguous free blocks.

Comment: Largest contiguous block will be hardly close to 8GB on 8GB systems because OS and all services/apps are also fed from the same pie. Consider system upgrade or make a temporary configuration with all unnecessary services/apps disabled to increase available RAM. You may also optimize MatLab starting mode with `-nodesktop` switch and others, see here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/startup-options.html